# How to read JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to figure out a lot of stuff and trying to improve in the grammar.

I've got the following `.js` code which was provided and i:

```
(function(document) {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-next]');

  for (const item of buttons) {

    const parentId = item.getAttribute('data-parent');

    const parent = document.querySelector(`#${parentId}`);

    const nextDivId = item.getAttribute('data-next');

    const nextDiv = document.querySelector(`#${nextDivId}`);

    if (!nextDiv) {
      console.error('could not find next div for button ', item);
    }

    item.addEventListener('click', function() {
      nextDiv.classList.toggle('hidden');
      parent.classList.toggle('hidden');
    });
  }
})(document);
```

The way I know how to write a function is

```
function nameFunction(nameVariable) {
   code here
}
```

So I'm not getting how the first `(function(document)` and last line work `})(document);`

Hope someone can educate me in this :) Many thanks!

Comment: const namFunction = (nameVariable,more) => {
 code here
}

Comment: You invoke the function immediately as you define it. Instead of the normal way of calling the function, you can wrap the function with brackets while providing the params next to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression). You can check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) for details information. You can also check this [stackoverflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228308/5146848)